# Lubuntu 20.04 desktop-number panel widget missing

Tags: 20.04, lubuntu, panel, widgets

I managed to replace Lub. 18.04 by 20.04 with preservation of all custom menus and keyboard shortcuts. It all works fine except one minor problem. In LXDE, there was a panel widget showing the desktop number. Such widget is absent in LXQt. I do not use the desktop switcher (it is removed from the panel; I rely on keyboard shortcuts), so not seeing the desktop number is annoying. There are obvious workarounds like jumping one desktop back and forth, but I would rather see the desktop number shown. Any suggestions?

Comment: The "*Desktop Switcher*" should show the current desktop you are using (how it shows it depends on the *theme* you're currently using, but on my system the "1" has a different background ot the numbers 2-5).  The page of the manual shows it (it's blue there in the first picture of the page) https://manual.lubuntu.me/stable/5/5.1/lxqt-panel.html

Comment: Please reread my question. I do not, and do not want to, use the desktop switcher.

Comment: You don't need to use (I use keyboard usually to switch mine), but it doubles as the indicator for your current desktop (even if you never click on it) as the currently selected virtual-desktop appears in a different color (or however your chosen theme displays it).

Comment: Once again: the keyboard switcher is not on my panel. I need some OTHER way of reporting the desktop number.

Comment: Lubuntu does not support the upgrade from 18.04 to 20.04, except through install.  Refer to the release notes (https://lubuntu.me/focal-1-released/) where you'll read "*Note, due to the extensive changes required for the shift in desktop environments, the Lubuntu team does not support upgrading from 18.04 or below to any greater release. Doing so will result in a broken system. If you are on 18.04 or below and would like to upgrade, please do a fresh install.*"  The widget is there on clean installs, the currently selected desktop appears as blue as per the picture in my first manual page link

Comment: Thanks for another useless comment. My "upgrade" was a new installation with preservation of /home and reusing the necessary *.desktop, *.directory and *.xml files. Takes some intimate knowledge of openbox, otherwise trivial.

Comment: I don't see anything else on LXQt's GitHub (no other suitable panel plugin), as they intend you to use the switcher as the indicator.